# Determine whether the series $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{n}{4(\ln n)^2}$ converge

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I've tried to apply integral test to this series,

$$
\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \ \frac{n}{4(\ln n)^2}
$$

which doesn't work since the result would be a special function. Can you give me a hint on this?

Comment: You don't need the integral test: it already fails the test of whether the terms go to zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We see that 
$$\lim _ { x \rightarrow \infty } \left( \frac { x } { 4 \ln \left( x ^ { 2 } \right) } \right) = \infty$$
$$\lim _ { x \rightarrow \infty } \left( \frac { x } { 4 \ln \left( x ^ { 2 } \right) } \right) = \frac { 1 } { 4 } \cdot \lim _ { x \rightarrow \infty } \left( \frac { x } { \ln \left( x ^ { 2 } \right) } \right)$$
We can apply L'Hopital's Rule 
$$= \frac { 1 } { 4 } \cdot \lim x \rightarrow \infty \left( \frac{1}{\frac{2}{x}} \right)$$
We simplify to get
$$= \frac { 1 } { 4 } \cdot \lim x \rightarrow \infty \left( \frac { x } { 2 } \right)$$
Which goes to infinity as $x$ goes to infinity. 
Therefore, this series does not converge.

Answer (score 0):

As noticed since $a_n \not \to 0$ the series diverges or as an alternative note that since eventually $\sqrt n \ge \log n$ we have

$$\frac{n}{4(\ln n)^2} \ge  \frac{1}{4(\ln n)^2} \ge \frac14\frac{1}{n}$$